# Querying Local PostGIS Database via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql, leaflet, postgis

I'm attempting to setup a local leaflet map that use from my local PostGIS database.  I've written a PHP file that does the querying but it doesn't seem to be working - I'm new to both Javascript and PHP and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot the issue I'm having.

Whenever I load the index.html, it runs an Ajax request on the PHP file. The  request simply fails without displaying any error messages.

I assume the problem lies in the PHP file but opening that hasn't helped much - the web console doesn't report any errors and all that is displayed is the following:

```
$attr{ // echo $attir.", "; //} //echo ";"; //}
```

Here is the PHP file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Query</h1>


<?php
    #header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    #Set header
    #header('Content-type: application/json');
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    #Get Data
    #$parameter1 = $_POST['lat'];
    #$parameter2 = $_POST['long'];

    $host= 'localhost';
    $port= '5432';
    $dbname = 'database';
    $user = 'user';
    $password = 'password';

    $conn = pg_connect("host=$host port=$port dbname=$dbname user=$user password=$password");
    if (!$conn) {
        echo "Not connected: " . pg_error();
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT *, ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom, 4326)) AS geojson FROM alb_cr.cr_point WHERE table_id = 761";

    if (!$response = pg_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Query failed";
        exit;
    }

    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($response)) {
        foreach ($row as $i => $attir) {
            echo $attir.", ";
        }
        echo ";";
    }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the Ajax request:

```
            $.ajax({
                type:     "GET",
                url:      "localhost/pull.php",
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    console.log('passed ' + data);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Failed"); 
                }
            });
```

Comment: Set `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Still nothing - is there a better way to debug this than through my browser?

Comment: Yeah, your web server's error log.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new to PHP and Javascript, I'll allow myself to give you few architectural suggestions, if I may say so.

First, you need to have your index.php (or whatever page should display query results, according to your design) to deliver page body with AJAX script incorporated into page body or (preferably) included as a separate script along with the rest of JS you might need, just like it is done for jQuery (which you use for AJAX).

```
<?php
//Output initial page contents
$html = <<<HTML
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--include jQuery library since, you use it for AJAX-call-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Query</h1>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <script>
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "localhost/pull.php",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    console.log('passed ' + data);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Failed"); 
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

echo $html;

?>
```

Next, I would use your separate localhost/pull.php to respond with query results when requested:

```
<?php
    $host= 'localhost';
    $port= '5432';
    $dbname = 'database';
    $user = 'user';
    $password = 'password';

    $conn = pg_connect("host=$host port=$port dbname=$dbname user=$user password=$password");
    if (!$conn) {
        echo "Not connected: " . pg_error();
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT *, ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom, 4326)) AS geojson FROM alb_cr.cr_point WHERE table_id = 761";

    if (!$response = pg_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Query failed";
        exit;
    }

    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($response)) {
        foreach ($row as $i => $attir) {
            echo $attir.", ";
        }
        echo ";";
    }

?>
```

With this, you should be able to get query results in desired format sent back into console when executing pull.php separately (or at least having it responded with some meaningfull errors).
After that, you may go client-side to see (in Developer Tools->Network) if your AJAX-request returned data to the browser.